# How to get suggestion channels by Youtube Data Api V3?

Tags: java, android, youtube

I used Youtube data api v3 to get videos and channels.
But it seem there are no ways to get suggestion channels by it. (Instead, should use v2)

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I use the youtube data v2.

The way is:

1. Use GoogleAuthUtil to get Access Token

2. Use HttpURLConnection to get Response.

You can get source code here https://github.com/KosbrotherSchool/YoutubeV2